Understanding Kotlin function
I'm having some problem understanding Kotlin class.
internal class TransformingSequence<T, R>
constructor(private val sequence: Sequence<T>, private val transformer: (T) -> R) : Sequence<R> {
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<R> = object : Iterator<R> {
        val iterator = sequence.iterator()
        override fun next(): R {
            return transformer(iterator.next())
        }

        override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
            return iterator.hasNext()
        }
    }

    internal fun <E> flatten(iterator: (R) -> Iterator<E>): Sequence<E> {
        return FlatteningSequence<T, R, E>(sequence, transformer, iterator)
    }
}

In the above code, I don't understand what iterator() function is doing. It seems like the function is inheriting from Iterator interface, and returning an object(?) inheriting Iterator interface...? And I don't get 'val iterator = sequence.iterator()' is for. Can somebody help?
Thank you in advance.

This is an object expression. It creates anonymous implementation of the Iterator interface and returns an instance of this class.
Inside curly braces there is a standard class definition, and it can access variables from the outer scope. Therefore, val iterator = sequence.iterator() simply creates a property in this class.
This code is an equivalent to:
internal class TransformingSequence<T, R>
constructor(private val sequence: Sequence<T>, private val transformer: (T) -> R) : Sequence<R> {
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<R> = MyIterator()
    
    private inner class MyIterator : Iterator<R> {
        val iterator = sequence.iterator()
        override fun next(): R {
            return transformer(iterator.next())
        }

        override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
            return iterator.hasNext()
        }
    }
}

From the high-level perspective, this class wraps an iterator inside another iterator and transforms all items on-the-fly. Whenever we ask for a next item from the wrapper iterator, it asks the internal iterator, transforms the item and returns.

So, iterator function is inheriting from interface right? And it returns an anonymous class inheriting Iterator interface. val iterator = sequence.iterator() is simply creating property of itself just as constructing class variable like Person person1 = new Person(). I thought it was causing a infinite recustion...
Sorry if what I'm saying doesn't make sense.

No, val iterator = sequence.iterator() retrieves an iterator from sequence, not of the inner, anonymous class. So no recursions here.

@JourneyToUngoro Functions don't inherit anything. Classes do. iterator function returns the Iterator type. I'm not entirely sure what do you mean about sequence.iterator(), but please note sequence is a sequence that was passed to the TransformingSequence when constructing it. val iterator = line creates an iterator over the sequence that we wrapped.

@broot I think now I get it.val iterator = sequence.iterator() is simply creating a iterator of given parameter in constructor. And overridden functions in the function iterator() is overriding the functions in the return anonymous class which inherits Iterator interface, right? Sorry if I'm bothering you...
